# past continous with present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-continuous

Can I use present perfect tense with past continuous tense.

> I have got  my credit card stolen  when I was shopping. I haven't got(ten) it back yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that **got** is  [sometimes used instead of "be" to form the passive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get), though it is uncommon and you have to use it in the same way:

> My credit card has been stolen.
>   My credit card has got stolen.

Furthermore, if you want to specify when it happened, you can't use present perfect with a specified time: you have to use simple past.

> My credit card has got stolen when I was shopping - **incorrect**
>   My credit card got stolen when I was shopping. - **correct**

You can use the rather more informal **I got** form, buy you must use simple past if you want to specify the time.

> I have got my credit card stolen when I was shopping - **incorrect**
>   I got my credit card stolen when I was shopping. - **correct**

There is a further problem with using **I have got** in this sentence, because it has a special meaning- **I have in my possession**. So your sentence seems to say

> [I have in my possession] my credit card stolen...

Reading it, it makes perfect sense until you get to **stolen**, then you go "woah! I wasn't expecting that".

Answer (score 0):

I would say that since you're talking about a specific incident that happened in the past, you should use the simple past in the first sentence:

> I got my credit card stolen when I was shopping. I haven't gotten it
>   back yet.

Or (probably more common):

> My credit card was stolen when I was shopping. I haven't gotten it
>   back yet.